# How to redirect all https:// requests to a subdomain on the server

Tags: apache, https, dns, centos, plesk

I need to redirect all https:// requests to a subdomain on my domain such as `apps.mysite.com`.

I know this is possible but what I do not know is how to deal with it, should I do this at DNS level or in some other way.

I have seen this on many other sites, fo example when you request `https://www.somesite.com`

the following message appears in Chrome

You attempted to reach www.somesite.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as apps.somesite.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of www.somesite.com.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

also when I check it through https://ssltools.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp I see the message

```
Certificate information
Common name:
 apps.somesite.com
SAN:
 apps.somesite.com
Valid from:
 2014-Mar-26 19:08:14 GMT
Valid to:
 2018-Jun-27 01:55:11 GMT
```

Can you please suggest something since I have never had to deal with all this before

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be possible to do this through rewrites at all, because the SSL connection will be established and throw validation errors before any redirects or rewrites occur. DNS is also probably out of the questions as it simply resolves a domain name to an IP address.

An argument could be made that this is almost against the design of SSL as it would allow you to basically set up an HTTPS site that redirects to another site without a valid certificate.

IE. I could set up a website accessible via https://facebook.com (via a hosts file attack on a users computer for example) and it could then redirect to https://fakebook.com and I would only have to have a valid certificate for fakebook.com, and not at all for facebook.com (which I obviously don't have). The user would most likely be none the wiser that I don't have a valid SSL cert for Facebook and I'm actually stealing all their data.